# Type alias for enum

Tags: rust

Is there a way to make the code below work? That is, export an enum under a type alias, and allow access to the variants under the new name?

```
enum One { A, B, C }

type Two = One;

fn main() {
    // error: no associated item named `B` found for type `One` in the current scope
    let b = Two::B;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think type aliases allow doing what you want, but you can rename the enum type in a `use` statement:

```
enum One { A, B, C }

fn main() {
    use One as Two;
    let b = Two::B;
}
```

You can use this in combination with `pub use` to re-export types under a different identifier:

```
mod foo {
    pub enum One { A, B, C }
}

mod bar {
    pub use foo::One as Two;
}

fn main() {
    use bar::Two;
    let b = Two::B;
}
```

Comment: Re-exporting does the trick - I guess it makes sense for enum types to behave more like mini-modules than structs and primitives.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone encounters this question, the original code now works as intended. This was added in [rust version 1.37.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/08/15/Rust-1.37.0.html#referring-to-enum-variants-through-type-aliases) in August 2019.